# Beginning Javascript Chapter 2 finishing exercise 2

Tags: javascript, parseint

I'm working through Beginning Javascript but can't get past Chapter 2 finishing exercise 2. The exercise is to correct this bit of code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 2, Finishing exercise 2</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var firstNumber = prompt("Enter the first number", "");
        var secondNumber = prompt("Enter the second number", "");
        var theTotal = firstNumber + secondNumber;

        document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " theTotal);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the correct total to display using alert, however when I remove the commenting it no longer works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 2, Finishing exercise 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var firstNumber = prompt("Enter the first number", "");
        var secondNumber = prompt("Enter the second number", "");


        var intFirstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber, 10);
        var intSecondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber, 10);
        var theTotal = intFirstNumber + intSecondNumber;


        alert(theTotal);
        //document.write (intFirstNumber + " added to " + intSecondNumber + " equals " theTotal);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out what about my document.write statement is wrong. Any hints? Additionally is there a more elegant way to achieve what I'm doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another `+` between the `"equals"` and `theTotal`:

```
document.write(firstNumber + " added to " + secondNumber + " equals " + theTotal);
```

In this context, the `+` sign means concatenate (append) whatever comes after it to whatever comes before it.

---

**Further Reading:**

[MDN documentation for string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition).

Comment: Thanks, this also simplified my answer as I could get rid of the separate `int` variables I created